# Git Push Hanging on one Repo (Pull is fine)

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github, push

Whenever I try to push my code in one Repo that I've not updated for a year or so, it hangs. This is the same via VSCode (sync), Terminal (git push) and GitHub Desktop (push).

I have some changes in a commit that I'd like to push to the remote.

Pull works fine (and says its upto date). Pushes on other repos are fine.

I've googled similar and not found any solutions. There are no large files.

```
Extension version:
VSCode Version: 1.86.1
OS: macOS Ventura Version 13.2.1 (22D68)
Repository Clone Configuration (single repository with one Main branch):
Github Product (Github.com):
```

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. git push

Terminal results...

```
chriswoods@Chriss-MBP-2 ChrisWoodsSays.github.io % git push
Enumerating objects: 12, done.
Counting objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 1.64 MiB | 1.11 MiB/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 4), reused 4 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
```

Then nothing. No blue dot. If I press ctrl C, I get the red dot to say its failed.

2. git pull
   Already up to date.

So that's OK.

3. When I first open VSCode, this is the Output.

I suspect my issue is the

```
2024-02-11 22:21:54.413 [info] > git config --local branch.main.github-pr-owner-number [18ms]
2024-02-11 22:21:54.413 [warning] git config failed: Failed to execute git
```

What is git config --local branch.main.github-pr-owner-number doing? How can I find out why it failed?

Note, although I am now seeing this error since trying various other things, I don't think that's the sync error as it was hanging before that happened

```
2024-02-11 22:21:54.067 [warning] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/chriswoods/Documents/GitHub/ChrisWoodsSays.github.io/.git/refs/remotes/origin/main'
```

Output

```
2024-02-11 22:21:53.888 [info] Log level: Info
2024-02-11 22:21:53.889 [info] Validating found git in: "/opt/homebrew/bin/git"
2024-02-11 22:21:53.906 [info] Using git "2.42.1" from "/opt/homebrew/bin/git"
2024-02-11 22:21:54.033 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [123ms]
2024-02-11 22:21:54.051 [info] > git rev-parse --git-dir --git-common-dir [13ms]
2024-02-11 22:21:54.054 [info] Open repository: /Users/chriswoods/Documents/GitHub/ChrisWoodsSays.github.io
2024-02-11 22:21:54.063 [info] > git config --get commit.template [7ms]
2024-02-11 22:21:54.063 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [6ms]
2024-02-11 22:21:54.066 [info] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) --ignore-case refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main [6ms]
2024-02-11 22:21:54.067 [warning] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/chriswoods/Documents/GitHub/ChrisWoodsSays.github.io/.git/refs/remotes/origin/main'
2024-02-11 22:21:54.069 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [5ms]
2024-02-11 22:21:54.072 [info] > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/main [5ms]
2024-02-11 22:21:54.075 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [5ms]
2024-02-11 22:21:54.085 [info] > git status -z -uall [12ms]
2024-02-11 22:21:54.085 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [8ms]
2024-02-11 22:21:54.095 [info] > git config --get commit.template [6ms]
2024-02-11 22:21:54.100 [info] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) --ignore-case refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main [6ms]
2024-02-11 22:21:54.100 [warning] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/chriswoods/Documents/GitHub/ChrisWoodsSays.github.io/.git/refs/remotes/origin/main'
2024-02-11 22:21:54.110 [info] > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/main [10ms]
2024-02-11 22:21:54.141 [info] > git status -z -uall [30ms]
2024-02-11 22:21:54.371 [info] > git ls-files --stage -- /Users/chriswoods/Documents/GitHub/ChrisWoodsSays.github.io/index.html [7ms]
2024-02-11 22:21:54.374 [info] > git show --textconv :index.html [11ms]
2024-02-11 22:21:54.379 [info] > git cat-file -s d5c71e85bbd595c588c19de033cece6db721b944 [6ms]
2024-02-11 22:21:54.413 [info] > git config --local branch.main.github-pr-owner-number [18ms]
2024-02-11 22:21:54.413 [warning] git config failed: Failed to execute git
2024-02-11 22:21:54.583 [info] > git check-ignore -v -z --stdin [5ms]
```

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but have you tried to clone the repo again in another location and push from there?